# problems with invoking the mouse events and giving input to the message box!

Tags: c#, mouseevent, messagebox, paint

My question seems a bit lengthy but I know the solution would be slight corrections to my code.I am implementing a sequence of 3 mouse events and a paint event in my form 1

pictureBox1_MouseDown,
pictureBox1_MouseMove,
pictureBox1_Paint,
pictureBox1_MouseUp.

the code should work this way: when i click the mouse and drag it and release the button at desired point then there should appear a custom message box which takes the input values.so i constructed a form(form2) which appears as message box. here is my code of form 1 ,you can understand the problem after seeing the code.

form1:

```
     private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // "e.X" and "e.Y" are used to get MousePositionX and MousePositionY
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.X, e.Y);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    } 
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // This makes sure that the left mouse button is pressed.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Draws the rectangle as the mouse moves

            rect.Width = e.X;
            rect.Height = e.Y;
        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }


    private WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2 _form2 = new WindowsFormsApplication2.Form2();

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogresult = _form2.ShowDialog(this);


        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    l[i] = e.X;
                    m[i] = e.Y;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

the problems here are:

1)According to the code when we drag the mouse a  rectangle appears and the place where we leave the mouse button a message box appears,now this message box(form2) is unable to read the input values as i dont know how to connect the OK and CANCEl buttons of form2 with the form1.After giving inputs and pressing OK the  rectangle should disappear,but here it is not happening.

2)I only need to give the input only two times,i.e i perform the previous sequence of actions(all the mouse events and paint event) only twice ,so i wrote FOR loop accordingly.But the problem is the  message box(form2) get fired every time, i release the mouse button.This is causing a serious problem as i have to implement a mousedoubleclick event after giving the two inputs.

Any please give say me  necessary corrections i have to make.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to guess what this code is trying to do.  What are l[] and m[]?  Why do you assign them to the position the mouse had before the dialog was shown?  I suspect you want to do something with *rect*.

Comment: I am trying to get the coordinates of mouse pointer into l[] and m[] and not sure whether their  declaration is correct  or not.I have to give inputs twice ,therefore my FOR loop is running twice.so those mouse pointer values will be stored in these arrays for further calculations that i have to make!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with "connect the OK and CANCEL buttons of form2 with form1"?

You don't have to "connect" anything. All you need is two buttons on Form2 (OK and Cancel) and in each _click method you need `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` for OK and `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;` for Cancel.

Then you continue with your "if" in Form 1.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = _form2.ShowDialog(this);

            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
            {                
                rect.Width = 0;
                rect.Height = 0;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

That will remove the Rectangle. I don't know if it's a good solution to do it, but it works.

Your Loop inside the Method can't work the way you want: every time you call `pictureBox1_MouseUp` and reach the for-loop 'i' will be set to '0' and then the loop starts.
You need a `int TwoClicks = 0` in constructor of Form1. And you have to change the `pictureBox1_MouseUp` accordingly:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TwoClicks < 2)
            {
            TwoClicks++;
            DialogResult dialogresult = _form2.ShowDialog(this);

            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
            {                
                rect.Width = 0;
                rect.Height = 0;
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
            }
        }
```

Feel free to ask any questions (and describe your first Problem, if I didn't get it right).

Comment: Thank you very much! you caught my intention in the right way!! when i press the buttons they should work according to the way you have said,if its OK it has to take the given values and if CANCEL it has  to ask again for input,but the TwoClicks should not be incremented at that point.

Comment: After giving the two inputs, when i double click on the picture box then the rectangle should not appear,but still it is appearing.

Comment: @raghu: you have to do the same trick with the "if (TwoClicks < 2)" in the mousedown (and probably in the mousemove too). that should work.